# Realistic Potential Wells

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, schroedinger-equation, terminology, potential

What is meant by the term "realistic" potential wells? I got stuck into the term as I don't know what are the limitations of the word realistic in this case.

For example mentioned in line

> *We will solve the time-dependent Schödinger equation by the spectral method for a given squeezed Gaussian wavepacket [11,12], adopting the realistic quartic DW potential. In order to investigate the influence of the initial state on dynamical properties, we adopt two squeezed Gaussian wavepackets with different parameters.*

From the paper

*Gaussian wavepacket dynamics and quantum tunneling in asymmetric double-well systems*

by 
Hideo Hasegawa

Physica A 392 (2013) 6232–6246 http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4110

Comment: You'll likely need to add some context. Can you copy down the problem or paragraph where you read it?

Comment: I have just edited the question to mention the reference where i read

Comment: Have you tried searching for "quartic DW potential"? That may get you somewhere.

Comment: yes i searched for it. If you see the paper which i mentioned then simply I can guess that the model discussed is said to be realistic as curvature of each minima of double well potential is same as curvature of harmonic oscillator. However, I don't know if I am right or wrong in concept. I was wondering if the term "realistic" has something to do with the theoretical model closer to experimental models? But I have no idea yet.

Comment: "realistic" *might* also be a funny way for the author to indicate it has no imaginary components anywhere

Comment: may be not @Jim which I can conclude from the line "In the past when quantum mechanics was
born, it was very difficult to numerically solve the time-dependent Schödinger equation even for a simple potential except
for a harmonic oscillator (HO) potential. One had to develop approximation methods applicable to simple tractable DW
models although they are not necessarily realistic." So realistic may be have something to do with the practical apllication. Not clear yet

Comment: @zenith I expect the authors mean "experimentally realisable and/or naturally occurring". I don't think it is worth getting stuck on this term: you won't find any sort of rigorous or universal definition of "realistic". What counts as "realistic" really depends on what system you are interested in looking at.

Comment: i was interested in the terminology as if some theoretical work is done by keeping in mind the experimental possibilities, then it is more worthy. That's why i stuck to the terminology of realistic potential wells

Answer (score 1):

By "realistic" potentials, what is generally meant is potentials that both a) have no infinite barriers or discontinuities and b) are meant to model, at least approximately, some kind of real-world phenomenon.

Comment: thank u for the explanation. Just for my curiosity, can you please help to find some literature in this respect?